# how to get result my code show me wrong result

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

> Write a function which accepts two arrays and inserts the first n elements of the second array into position x of the first array and adds the remaining elements of the second array to the end.

`InsertElements(arr1 = [1,2,3,9], arr2 = [4,7,2], pos = 3, count = 2)` should return `[1,2,4,7,3,9,2]`

```
static void getresult(int []a, int []b, 
                            int n, int m)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int j;

            for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
                if (a[i] == b[j])
                    break;

            if (j == m)
                Console.Write(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void Main()
    {
        int []a = {1, 2, 3, 9};
        int []b = {4,7,2};

        int n = a.Length;
        int m = b.Length;

        getresult(a, b, n, m);
    }
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: You need to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it line by line.  If you don't know how, start learning [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Once you've done that, you can probably make a bit more progress on your own. At the very least, you need to be able to tell us EXACTLY where and how the behaviour of the code differs from your expectation and what data is in use at the time. If you can't tell us that then you haven't done enough research of your own.

Comment: And what do you get instead of the desired result? What is your question?

Comment: i want result [1,2,4,7,3,9,2] like this

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is a great post for learning how to debug

Comment: The assignment question you quoted indicates that you need to produce a single, combined array from your method.  How are you going to do that from a `void` method that doesn't have a `ref` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure about position of 3 according to your Example but here is code which produces desired output:-

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 9 };
        int[] b = { 4, 7, 2 };

        int position = 3;
        int count = 2;

        getresult(a, b, position, count);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

            static void getresult(int[] a, int[] b,
                        int n, int m)
    {
        int firstArrayCount = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < n-1 ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a[i]);

            firstArrayCount++;
        }

        for(int i=0; i < m ; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b[i]);
        }

        for(int i=firstArrayCount;i<a.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
        }

        for(int i=m;i<b.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's rather funny that this has been accepted as an answer when it doesn't actually do as requested.  This code may display the elements of the two arrays as requested but it doesn't create a single combined array, which is what the instructions specify.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions might be this one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 9 };
        int[] b = { 4, 7, 2 };

        InsertElements(a, b, 3, 2);
    }

    private static void InsertElements(int[] arr1, int[] arr2, int x, int n)
    {
        var listOfArr1 = arr1.ToList();
        var itemsToInsert = arr2.Take(n);
        var itemsToAdd = arr2.Skip(n);

        var pos = x - 1;

        foreach (var item in itemsToInsert)
        {
            listOfArr1.Insert(pos, item);
            pos++;
        }

        listOfArr1.AddRange(itemsToAdd);

        var result = listOfArr1.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a homework question, so generic `Lists` have likely not even been covered yet and LINQ would certainly not have been.

Comment: @Addi do you passing these arguments? 
`
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 9 };
            int[] b = { 4, 7, 2 };

            InsertElements(a, b, 3, 2);
`